# Is there a linux distribution that fully mimics mac keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, macintosh

I know that there are Linux distributions (e.g: ubuntu) that can be partially adapted to physical mac keyboard and its layout but it is clunky and only covers some scenarios. I was hoping there is one distro that specifically supports such layout out of the box.
I am particularly interested in these Mac-like keyboard shortcuts:

- cancel an app in terminal: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- and copy to clipboard: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Ideally, I'd want to see a distro deriving from Debian, Redhat or even Alpine that has:

- majority of window keys covered (switching between apps, closing windows, refreshing web pages in a browser, etc).
- apps such as word processor, file editor, terminal and browser; support copying and pasting in Mac style using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
- has a search box, similar to Apple's Spotlight Search

Comment: I have a set up like this on my Windows with WSL computer using autohotkey.  You will need to disable the windows key using regedit.  It not exactly what I would call easy but can be down.

Comment: `cancel an app in terminal: CTRL+C` - this is already handled by kernel stty driver

Comment: Are you needing a whole distro, or would a key-mapping be sufficient.

Comment: The first one <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, is standard Unix, what are you seeing that is wrong?

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked, and OP has not responded to comments. Unless it is made clear, no answer can be given. (making it clear will have a better affect than a bounty.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor On the contrary, the [timeline of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/390270/timeline) looks fine; nobody had flagged for being unclear or had such comment until you did. OP probably wanted to achieve a fully functioning mac keyboard on Linux that behaves just like in macOS, from what I understand.

Comment: @clearkimura If being the first to discover something makes one wrong, then I am wrong. I was only trying to help. If my help is not needed, that is fine. I honestly don't care enough.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I spent some time searching for posts before I decided to put a bounty to draw attention. My comment merely states the fact that the question looks fine until now; it is up to you to interprete it negatively. The bounty was freely given and may be wasted as a result.